# Writing a function in matlab syntax

Tags: matlab

I wrote a function named "Maximizing Gross margin" that is used in agriculture. The formula is like this:

max sigma(i=1 to n) sigma(j=1 to nc) (Pij * Yij - SDij ... (and so on) ) ...

full formula in this link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMSiU.jpg

I think it doesn't have the real matlab's syntax and it is not really calculates the maximum. And there are two other formulas that I want to mix with this and link them to the evolutionary algorithm (NSGA-II) and I really don't know how, although I confused myself searching for it.

This is my function in matlab:

```
function gx = costfunction( p,y,sd,fer,lb,oc,a,wp,Q,ma)
SigmaQNC = zeros(5,3);
SigmaNC = zeros(5,3);
for i=1:5
for j=1:3
    SigmaQNC(i,j) = SigmaQNC(i,j) + Q(i,1);
    SigmaNC(i,j) =  (p(i,j).*y(i,j))-(sd(i,j)-fer(i,j)-lb(i,j)-oc(i,j)-ma(i,j)).*a(i,j)-wp(i,j).*SigmaQNC(i,j);
    sort(SigmaNC);
end
end
gx=SigmaNC;
end
```

The question is, how to really write it in matlab syntax and how to link these three formulas to NSGA-II with the limitations (like min Aij <= percentage Aij <= max Aij )

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `Aij`? A fixed value, a variable? Is min Aij and max Aij, a notation for the smallest and biggest value in the matrix?

Comment: Your formula doesn't make sense. The result of the nested sums is a single number (since you're summing over all available indices, `i` and `j`). Why would one take the maximum of a single number? So there must be something more that you should tell about the terms of your sum; please do tell us. :-)

Comment: @patrik : 'A' stands for area. it means they want to have the maximum profit according to the expenses (like labour, machine etc) and the question is what amount of 'A' (area under soil) is good for max profit, and we should consider that we have a limitation here: the precentage of A should be between the minimum and maximum amount of A.

Comment: @CST-Link : Sorry, and yes, i know it is a poor work :( ... I don't know how to write the formula to find the maximum number possible. I can tell you this example: cos(x) . the maximum of y is 1 and x would be pi, 2*pi, 3*pi ... . so if you want the max of y, you set the x to pi or 2*pi ... . the question is, how to write this formula so it can find the maximum possible number of A ? I hope I cleared it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, your formula is not in MATLAB syntax. If I understood correctly, you want to maximize this objective function which is done by NSGA-II with other objective functions. For optimization max f = -min f.

Comment: Dear Flexo, You are right, it is not in MATLAB syntax. you understood correctly and I want exatcly what you have said. But I dont know how to do it. I would be grateful if you taught me. TNX.